# Is there an easy way to compare paths of binary tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I need to find a word that is the highest in an alphabetical order.

path from leaf to root without sidetracking like XHCA, FHCA, XFA, GFA in example below

**Example:**

```
INPUT  
      A
     / \
    C   F
   /   / \ 
  H   X   G
 / \
X   F

OUTPUT
XHCA
```

My function to find the highest word:

```
String find(){
        String wordLeft = "", wordRight = "";
        if(left != null) wordLeft += left.find() + getValue();
        if(right != null) wordRight += right.find() + getValue();

        return left == null && right == null ? String.valueOf(getValue()) : left == null ? wordRight : right == null ? wordLeft : compare(wordLeft, wordRight);
    }
    String compare(String wordLeft, String wordRight){
        if(wordLeft.compareTo(wordRight) > 0) return wordLeft;
        else if(wordLeft.compareTo(wordRight) < 0) return wordRight;
        else return wordLeft.length() > wordRight.length() ? wordLeft : wordRight;
    }
```

It works with most inputs, however the output is incorrect with one bigger tree (too big for me to find where the bug occurs or even post it here as it is over 260000 nodes all in .txt file). I couldn't find any smaller tree that has similar bug.

My questions:

- Are there any logical issues with my algorithm?
- Is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Source code:

```
public class Tree{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        String line;
        Node root = new Node('+'); //Replacement value until we find the proper root
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            line = sc.nextLine();
            char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
            if(arr.length > 2){
                root.addNode(arr);
            }else if(arr.length == 1){
                root.setValue(arr[0]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(root.find());
    }
}

class Node {
    char value;
    Node right, left;
    Node(char value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    void addNode(char[] arr){
        if(arr.length == 3){
            if(arr[2] == 'L') {
                if (left == null) left = new Node('/');
                left.setValue(arr[0]);
            }
            if(arr[2] == 'R') {
                if (right == null) right = new Node('\\');
                right.setValue(arr[0]);
            }
        }else if(arr.length > 3){
            char[] newArr = new char[arr.length - 1];
            newArr[0] = arr[0];
            newArr[1] = arr[1];
            for(int i = 2; i < newArr.length; i++){
                newArr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            }

            if(arr[2] == 'L') {
                if (left == null) left = new Node('/');
                left.addNode(newArr);
            }
            if(arr[2] == 'R') {
                if (right == null) right = new Node('\\');
                right.addNode(newArr);
            }
        }
    }

    String find(){
        String wordLeft = "", wordRight = "";
        if(left != null) wordLeft += left.find() + getValue();
        if(right != null) wordRight += right.find() + getValue();

        return left == null && right == null ? String.valueOf(getValue()) : left == null ? wordRight : right == null ? wordLeft : compare(wordLeft, wordRight);
    }
    String compare(String wordLeft, String wordRight){
        if(wordLeft.compareTo(wordRight) > 0) return wordLeft;
        else if(wordLeft.compareTo(wordRight) < 0) return wordRight;
        else return wordLeft.length() > wordRight.length() ? wordLeft : wordRight;
    }
    char getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
    void setValue(char value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the input for the 'big tree'?

Comment: `however it has problem` what problem does it have? does it throw an exception (if yes paste the stacktrace)? does it give incorrect output? or maybe something else (too slow?)?

Comment: You haven't told us what a "word" is. For example, is `CAF` a word? If not, why not?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia
not really as it has over 260000 nodes

Comment: @jannis
It gives incorrect output. Instead of "ZZZZZ" I got "ZZZZYSDZZZZ".

Comment: @user3386109
CAF is not a word. Word is a full path from leaf to root with no sidetracking.
Example:
XHCA, FHCA, XFA, GFA

Comment: So the algorithm should be a DFS that accumulates a word in reverse order as it descends. When it reaches a leaf, reverse the word and compare with the best word so far.